# How to set default db in rethink dashboard?

Tags: rethinkdb

How can I use the `conn.use('db')` command in the `rethinkdb` dashboard to set the default database.  The `conn` object seems unavailable in that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment. 
They're planning to add this feature. See [#2948](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/2948).